# How to stop a convoy?

Tags: ghost-recon-wildlands

I am really struggling to stop convoys so that I can tag the supplies.

I've tried strafing the convoy with a chopper which is difficult, I've tried C4 and Mines, both of which seem to work, but the target vehicle still just drives away.

I've taken out both escort vehicles in the convoy, shot the tyres of the truck and still it drives away.

What is the secret to effectivly stopping a convoy in a clean and efficient manner?

Comment: You can destroy the target vehicle and still tag it, however you will only get half of the resources it's suppose to give you. At a certain amount of damage however, the driver will get out of the vehicle and run. I believe if they also get stuck they will also do this.

Comment: It's worth noting that since Title Update 6, helicopters now have an aiming reticule which makes helicopter vs convoy much easier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Currently, I use this following method:

- Equip the EMP drone
- Equip the M203 grenade launcher on your assault rifle
- Upgrade the grenade launcher to at least level 2 or higher
- You will have better success with the a higher level emp drone as well with this strat

Use the map to see the projected path of the convoy and put yourself in position to ambush them, but do not ambush them by an enemy base.   While under cover, equip your M203 and then switch to your drone.   Fly your drone **without being detected** to the middle of the convoy right as it is about to pass you and deploy your EMP.  **The EMP will shutdown all 3 vehicles if your drone is upgraded enough and deployed in the correct location.** Immediately after you deployed your EMP, shoot your M203 grenades into the front vehicle and into the back vechicle (usually 3 each).  Then take out the passenger and the driver (he usually surrenders) of the center vehicle.  Once this is done, mark the vehicle and collect your supplies!  This strategy, if worked correctly, takes about 30-40 seconds to complete cleanly.

Comment: emp drones can be deployed from choppers (as a passenger), so it can be useful to emp the convoy in order to get ahead of them.

Comment: i had no idea you could disable cars with emp drones... really though if you think about it...Truck and EMP? lol

Answer (score 6):

OK, my son came up with a really good convoy-stopping system that is almost a 100% guaranteed success and is as easy as taking the proverbial candy away from a baby.  The only real risk of failure is if you should be spotted by some random UNIDAD unit or attempt stopping the convoy too close to a hostile base or encampment.  OK, here's how it's done....

Simply arm yourself with a LMG, you can call "guns-for-hire" if you want, it's helpful but not really necessary.  Position yourself at minimum, 500 meters ahead of the convoy and lay prone on the side of the road and wait for the convoy to get to 300 meters from you.  At 300 meters, open up on the supply truck in the center of the convoy.  Once it's damage is at 50%, it will stop and go no further. If you have maxed out the "vehicle damage" skill, you will stop the convoy very, very quickly.  Stay where you are and take out the hostile support guys at range.  If UNIDAD doesn't get involved, you have all the time in the world to pick off the bad guys and then go take your spoils.

This method usually takes all of about 5 to 10 seconds to stop the convoy and perhaps another minute or so to kill all the baddies and tag the truck.  Couldn't be easier!  You'll have resources coming out of your ears in no time.

Word of caution.  Once we think we've taken care of all the bad guys, we usually send the drone over to take a look.  We've noticed that there seems to often be one or two guys that have held back at the rear escort vehicle, or have run unnoticed off to the side of the road and aren't where you'd expect them to be, they have a tendency to surprise you when you approach the supply truck.  Use the drone, find'em, tag'em and bag'em.  Have fun, you'll be a pro stagecoach robber in no time.

Answer (score 1):

I've also found that upgrading the VHS Destruction skill makes convoys very easy.  When fully upgraded along with the bonus medal, you do 100% more bullet damage to vehicles including helicopters.

Equip either an assault rifle or LMG (I like to have both).  If you are playing with a friend, drive alongside the convoy and open fire on the convoy vehicle. Once it's health reaches about a quarter, it will stop, along with the other vehicles. Be careful not to destroy the vehicle! Take out the enemies by any means (I've also found that the grenade launcher makes this simple), and tag the vehicle. Takes about a minute or so at most with a good teammate.

If you aren't playing with a teammate, get ahead of the convoy and wait for it to approach you.  You can place some mines on the road to take out the lead escort vehicle, and then open fire on the convoy vehicle to stop it. Take out the other convoy vehicle and tag the supplies. This way doesn't take much longer either depending on how far up the road you go.

Answer (score 1):

And for all the players that don't have 17 levels of playtime (I'm assuming we're talking about single player here) just get into a four door car, press <kbd>F</kbd> (Order Attack) once, and stay with the convoy. Your guys will take out both cars and will damage the convoy vehicle badly enough so that it will stop and you can tag it.

This method only fails if you can't keep up with the convoy.

Comment: What does F do? I have the game for Xbox so what does F translate to?

Comment: @TimmyJim Ah sorry. Its "Order attack"

Comment: Its either up or left on the dpad, xbox or pc controller

Answer (score 1):

The trick is not to upgrade the vehicle damage skill past two points. Without upgrading it, the HTI will disable the main truck in one bullet and still kill helicopters in one shot.

If you’ve fully upgraded vehicle damage you’re boned, the SRSA1 and L115A3 can both disable the main vehicle in two shots, but helicopters will also take 2-3 which is dicey with high tier mode. Still the best bet, as the EMP is unreliable and the LMG trick will likely get you killed at least once.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way: post up somewhere ahead, send up the drone, and use rebel spotting on the vehicles, then mark the two in the convoy vehicle with sync shot, and anyone else of your choosing, then just have them fire. 100% effectiveness and no damage to the truck, so if a car next to it blows up then you aren't fucked, though you should try to tag it as soon as possible if something like that happens.

Answer (score 0):

I also use the EMP, M203 method just as described in the previous post.  It seems to be the most effective and efficient way to go about it.  Another method, though not very efficient for those supply vehicles equipped with bullet proof windshields, is to position yourself fairly far down the road from the convoy so that they are aligned in a one behind the other formation as they approach you.  Use the EMP drone to stop them and then open fire from distance at the first escort vehicle and also try to damage the supply vehicle enough so that it can't drive away or the driver runs off.  The second escort vehicle can't attack very efficiently because it's blocked by the other vehicles in front of it. Your chance of survival is improved because of the distance.  I've done this with some degree of success using the EMP, semi-auto sniper rifle and M203's.

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to stop them by getting a vehicle and ordering the team to open fire, damaging the vehicles. Sometimes the supply truck has been caught on fire and I have to quickly tag it, or after it's destroyed tag it.

I've put down mines but civilian vehicles end up running over them. I've tried C4 but once you trigger it the supply truck takes off so I have to find a car and give chase. I tried to snipe the driver from down the road but the front car gets in the way. I have also tried hitting the window of the supply truck but didn't stop it.

Answer (score 0):

I have one point into vehicle damage, and I use the HTI sniper rifle, one shot to the convoy will stop it without destroying it. Then just take your time killing the guys but make sure not to hit the convoy.